# Like box not showing photos anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox, facebook-timeline

For my website www.donelli.nl im using the Facebook likebox.
It worked good for a few weeks but now something strange has happend.

Since yesterday the likebox is not showing pictures anymore. I have changed nothing in the settings, it just happend.

So now when im placing a post on my Facebook everything is fine on Facebook. But its not on my website. In the like box only the text appears and not the picture.
Can somebody please help me?

Kind Regards,

David

Answer (score 0):

This is "by design".  The limited space of social plugins like the Like Box and Activity Feed means FB has to display 'compact' versions of large stories like photos.  If you look at the CSS, you'll see the DIVs are tagged '!important' (not important).

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how i can fix it ?